# Dropdownlists with parent-child relation in EditItemTemplate Gridview not working

Tags: asp.net, gridview, cascadingdropdown

I have a page with `gridview` in it.

My `gridview` shows the products Information and Admin can `Edit gridviews columns`.

Two of my `columns` show the `brand name` and `category name` for each product;

I use lables in ItemTemplate tag in my grid view to show these two columns value and I use two `dropdownlists`(branddrop,categorydrop) 

in my `EditItemTemplate` tag for editing these two columns value,when admin select an item in branddrop the categorydrop should show categories name which are related to selected brand name in branddrop.

Brands name in my brand table in database are:

> Samsung, Nokia,Sony Ericsson,Apple,LG,HTC....

and my categories name in category table are :

> Galaxy Nexus,Galaxy Tab 2 7. 0,Galaxy S3,Asha,Lumia,iPhone,iPad,Xperia Arc,Xperia Neo,Xperia X8,Cookie 3g,Cookie lite,Km555e,Optimus l9,Optimus elite,Optimus g,wt18i,w8,500,n8...

When I click the `Edit button`, first item in the branddrop is Equal to brandlable.
Text  in ItemTemplate and it works fine my problem is  the first item in category drop is not Equal to categorylable.
text in ItemTemplate and the category drop does not show the related categories name to brandname.
for every product it shows iphone and ipad  so I have to select another items in branddrop and then select again the related brandname which is related to that product then the categorydrop can show the list of related categories name.
I tried to use `brandDrop_SelectedIndexChanged` and `GridView1_RowEditing` but it is not work.
 I dont know how to solve it.

this is my first code:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="brand name">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="brandname" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("brand_name") %>'></asp:Label>
                <asp:Label ID="idfrombrand" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("idfrombrands") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="br" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("idfrombrands") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Label><%--OnSelectedIndexChanged="brandDrop_SelectedIndexChanged" --%> 

                <asp:DropDownList  ID="brandDrop" runat="server" DataTextField="brand_name" DataValueField="id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource4" AutoPostBack="true"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="brandDrop_SelectedIndexChanged" >
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource4" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:mobile_storeConnectionString2 %>" SelectCommand="select [id],[brand_name] from [brands]" ></asp:SqlDataSource>
            </EditItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="category name">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="catname" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("category_name") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
           <EditItemTemplate>
               <asp:Label ID="OldCatName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("idfromCategories") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
               <asp:DropDownList ID="categoryDrop" runat="server"  AutoPostBack="true" DataTextField="category_name" DataValueField="id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3">   <%-- --%>
               </asp:DropDownList>
               <asp:Label ID="cat" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("idfromCategories") %>' Visible="false" ></asp:Label>
              <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server"   ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:mobile_storeConnectionString2 %>" SelectCommand="select [category_name],[id],[idfrombrands] from [categories] where idfrombrands=@idfrombrands " >
                <SelectParameters>
                  <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="brandDrop" 
                    Name="idfrombrands" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32"  />
                </SelectParameters>
               </asp:SqlDataSource>

           </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

> this is my code behind for GridView1_RowDataBound and GridView1_RowUpdating:

```
 protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
     int brand=0;
    int category=0;
    //Drop Brand--------------------------------------

    DropDownList list1 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("brandDrop");
    Label lbl = (Label)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("br");

    if (list1.SelectedItem.Value != null)
    {
       brand  = Convert.ToInt32(list1.SelectedItem.Value);//NewIdFromBrand

    }
    else
    {
        brand = Convert.ToInt32(lbl.Text);

    }
    //Drop Category----------------------------------------

   DropDownList list2 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("categoryDrop");
   Label lbl2 = (Label)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("OldCatName");

    //int NewIdFromBrand2 = -1;
    if (list2.SelectedItem.Value != null)
    {
       category  = Convert.ToInt32(list2.SelectedItem.Value);//NewIdFromBrand2

    }
    else
    {

        category = Convert.ToInt32(lbl2.Text);
    }

    //Photo-------------------------------------------

    string photoname = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    FileUpload fileUpload = row.FindControl("FileUploadimg") as FileUpload;
    Label lbl3 = (Label)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("oldImage"); 
    if (fileUpload != null && fileUpload.HasFile)
    {
        fileUpload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/P_Image") + photoname + fileUpload.FileName);

        SqlDataSource1.UpdateParameters["path"].DefaultValue = "~/P_Image" + photoname + fileUpload.FileName;
    }
    else
    {
     SqlDataSource1.UpdateParameters["path"].DefaultValue = lbl3.Text;//oldImage.Text;
    }
    int prid = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value);
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection();
    cn.ConnectionString = "server = . ; database = mobile_store ; Trusted_Connection=true";
    DataTable tb = new DataTable();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = cn;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = "UpdateProduct";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@brandid", brand );
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@catid", category );
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pid", prid);
    try
    {
        cn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        SqlDataSource1.DataBind();

    }
    catch (Exception ex2)
    {


    }
    finally { cn.Close(); }
    //GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
    //GridView1.DataBind();

}

protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        //check if is in edit mode
        if ((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0)
        {
            DataRowView dRowView1 = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                if ((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0)
                {
                    DropDownList ddlStatus = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("brandDrop");
                    ddlStatus.SelectedValue = dRowView1["brandId"].ToString();
                    DropDownList ddlStatus2 = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("categoryDrop");
                    ddlStatus2.SelectedValue = dRowView1["categoryID"].ToString();
                    //Label1.Text = ddlStatus.SelectedValue;

                }
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8056408/asp-net-gridview-refresh-with-cascading-dropdown-controls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you so much Abide Masaraure.you helped me a lot.
I deleted grideview_rowediting and braddrop_selectedIndexChange event And just added two lines to my GridView1_RowDataBound event.

```
 SqlDataSource sq = (SqlDataSource)e.Row.FindControl("SqlDataSource3");
 sq.SelectParameters["idfrombrands"].DefaultValue = dRowView1["brandId"].ToString();
```

now my event is like this:

```
  protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        //check if is in edit mode
        if ((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0)
        {
            DataRowView dRowView1 = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                if ((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0)
                {
                    DropDownList ddlStatus = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("brandDrop");
                    ddlStatus.SelectedValue = dRowView1["brandId"].ToString();
                    DropDownList ddlStatus2 = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("categoryDrop");
                    ddlStatus2.SelectedValue = dRowView1["categoryID"].ToString();

                    SqlDataSource sq = (SqlDataSource)e.Row.FindControl("SqlDataSource3");
                    sq.SelectParameters["idfrombrands"].DefaultValue = dRowView1["brandId"].ToString();
                }
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I need to see your code you are using in your selected index changed event.

The following  cascading drop down technique will take away all the suffering you have  in trying to hook up the  parent and its children...I use this wonderful feature in the Ajax control toolkit in all my projects.You can use any data retrieval method you want as long it returns an array.I am using linq in this example for data retrieval.
Assuming I have  tables named Brand and Model and classes : Brand and Model and collections: Brands and Models

**In 'YourWebServicePath.asmx'** (Web service file)

```
 <WebMethod()> _
    Public Function GetBrands(knownCategoryValues As String, category As String) As  CascadingDropDownNameValue()

        Dim result = From b As Bands In Brand.Brands Select New CascadingDropDownNameValue(b.BrandDesc, b.BrandID.ToString())
        Return result.ToArray()

    End Function


<WebMethod()> _
Public Function GetModels(knownCategoryValues As String, category As String) As CascadingDropDownNameValue()
    Dim brandID As Guid
    Dim brandValues As StringDictionary = AjaxControlToolkit.CascadingDropDown._
   ParseKnownCategoryValuesString(knownCategoryValues)
     brandID = New Guid(brandValues("Brand"))
    Dim result = From m As Models In Model.GetModels() Where m.brandID = brandID       Select New CascadingDropDownNameValue(m.ModelDesc, 
 _ m.ModelID.ToString())
    Return result.ToArray()
   End Function
```

**MarkUp**

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>

    <EditItemTemplate>

                <asp:DropDownList  ID="dropBrand" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" >
                </asp:DropDownList>


                    <cc1:CascadingDropDown ID="BrandCascadingDropDown"
                                           runat="server"
                                           Category="Brand"
                                           TargetControlID="dropBrand"
                                           PromptText="-Select Brand-"
                                           LoadingText="Loading Brands.."
                                           ServicePath="YourWebServicePath.asmx"

                                           ServiceMethod="GetBrands">
                   </cc1:CascadingDropDown>

</EditItemTemplate>

<EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList  ID="dropModel" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" >
                </asp:DropDownList>


           <cc1:CascadingDropDown ID="ModelCascadingDropDown"
                                           runat="server"
                                           Category="Model"
                                           TargetControlID="dropModel"
                                           ParentControlID="dropBrand"
                                           PromptText="-Select Model-"
                                           LoadingText="Loading Models.."

                                           ServicePath="YourWebServicePath.asmx"
                                           ServiceMethod="GetModels" >
                    </cc1:CascadingDropDown>
```

And thats all you need.No need of wiring the events.And voila! let the toolkit perform the magic.

Comment: thanks for your reply.I have not put anything in my  selected index changed event, and categorydrop works fine when I select an Item from branddrop.it does not work well when I click edit button .because I use sqldatasource I dont need to use selected index change event,when I select an item from branddrop ,the categorydrop shows related categories name but when I click edit button because I still do not select any item from brand drop it does not work well .I dont know how to solve it

Answer (score 0):

Eureka!!!.You owe me a cup of coffee.I replicated your problem and realized after two hours that you need to actually hook to your index selected changed event.The trick is to use the naming container property to locate your drop downs,they think are pretty hidden ,but the sender argument enables us to expose them when dropband dropdown fires. And presto everything works like a charm.

Use this code snipet in your selected changed event.

```
protected void dropBand_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{

DropDownList dropBand = (DropDownList)sender;

SqlDataSource dsc = (SqlDataSource)dropBand.NamingContainer.FindControl("SqlDataSource3");
DropDownList categoryDrop = (DropDownList)dropBand.NamingContainer.FindControl("categoryDrop");
dsc.SelectParameters("BrandID").DefaultValue = dropBand.SelectedValue;
categoryDrop.DataBind();
}
```

I can send you  a zip file of the demo this time if you happen to continue having issue.Happy Coding!!!.
[image: Debug]

Comment: thank you so much for spending your time to solve my problem,I used it but it is the same as before.I need to put  your codes like  dsc.SelectParameters["idfrombrands"].DefaultValue= dropBand.SelectedValue; in event wich happen when I click edit button and before happening select index change event.you know I have productname,product price and sth else in each row may be the admin click edit button and edit only the product price and when he click the update button the wrong value of category name set to my product information

Comment: I mean it set my product category name to 'iphone' so this condition force the admin to select again the brand name each time he wants to edit the product info.my problem is I dont know which event fire when I click the edit .

Comment: I used this code on gridviw_rowediting 
        SqlDataSource sq = (SqlDataSource)GridView1.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].NamingContainer.FindControl("SqlDataSource3");
        DropDownList categorydrop = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].NamingContainer.FindControl("categoryDrop");
        DropDownList branddrop = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].NamingContainer.FindControl("brandDrop");       
        sq.SelectParameters["idfrombrands"].DefaultValue = branddrop.SelectedValue;
        categorydrop.DataBind();but null error happens,branddrop,categorydrop,sq is null

Answer (score 0):

To use the above code i gave you in a row editing event you have to modify it like so.Then those objects won't be null.

```
 protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    GridView testgrid = (GridView)(sender);
    testgrid.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    testgrid.DataBind();
    DropDownList dropBand = (DropDownList)testgrid.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("ddlProducts");

    //
}
```

Something is definitely happening in your page cycle and is keeping on biting you.I suggest zip an mdf of your database and the offending aspx page and let me tackle it from here if you don't get it to work.Never give up.

[image]